# mi messagebox no funciona

Tags: python, messagebox

Tengo éste código que quiero para que aparezca un mensaje cuando finalice el proceso, pero no logro hacer que me funcione.    estoy usando customtkinter para la interfaz el cual tengo importado como ctk.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def verify_data(self):
        data = self.entry_1.get()
        count = self.api_check(data)
        if count:
            ctk.messagebox.showwarning("Datos comprometidos",
                                       f'Los datos "{data}" fueron encontrados {count} veces.')
        else:
            ctk.messagebox.showinfo("Datos seguros",
                                    f'Los datos "{data}" no fueron encontrados.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo probe y Obtuve este error """AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'messagebox' """

Encontre esto, y funciona:
https://github.com/Akascape/CTkMessagebox

En resumen tienes que instalar una libreria especifica:
pip install CTkMessagebox

y usarlo de esta manera:
from CTkMessagebox import CTkMessagebox
import customtkinter

```
CTkMessagebox(title="Info", message="This is a CTkMessagebox!")
```

Te recomiendo ir al la pagina de github para que conozcas mas opciones de configuracion del cuadro de dialogo.